# How to insert counter counter #excelvba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a modified macro from the internet. This macro is copying/moving files from one folder to another based on the list in Excel not all files in source folder. My goals to is prompt the user how many files have been successfully copied.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
Dim xVal As String
Dim xCount As Long

ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a1000").Select 'List of Files to copy from source to destination folder

On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "Files Selected", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the Source folder:"

If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the Destination folder:"

If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
For Each xCell In xRg
    xVal = xCell.Value
    If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
        FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        Kill xSPathStr & xVal 'Delete files from SOURCE
    End If
Next
  Msgbox '(This prompt USER for count of successful copied files)
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help

Rey

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add 1 to a variable and then to display this variable in, say, a message box

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
Dim xVal As String
Dim xCount As Long

ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a5000").Select 'Select active cells

On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "Files Selected", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the Source folder:"

If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the Destination folder:"

If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
For Each xCell In xRg
    xVal = xCell.Value
    If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
        FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Kill xSPathStr & xVal
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Task finished. " & xCount & " files were succesfully copied.", vbInformation, "Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the reply, its running but the result of counting is from the number of pre selected cells (ActiveSheet.Range("a4:a5000").Select it returns 4997 count.) not the total copied files. Like I have put only 50 lists on the pre selected it will results on how many count of available files from SOURCE folder.

Comment: Isn't `FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal` the line that copies a file? Each time that runs the counter goes up by one. If the counter returns 4997, than the aforementioned line has also been run 4997 times